# Schedule a Mule 3.0 flow in Cloudhub

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mule-esb, cloudhub

I have a Mule 3.0 flow which does a set of operations and works fine. I can deploy this fine on my cloudhub platform as well. Now the question is, how can I define schedule for this in the cloud, so that it is scheduled to run at a specific interval? Should I be defining something at a flow level (maybe a poll or something?). Please share your thoughts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Schedules in CloudHub are generated automatically from Poll scopes that are already present as message sources in your flows.

Note that the only current Mule 3.x versions for CloudHub applications are 3.8 or 3.9. All previous versions are deprecated. I'm not sure that Mule 3.0 ever made it to CloudHub.